# How to share current URL using a WhatsApp share button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whatsapp

I have a blog app build on rails, i was searching on how to add a share button for WhatsApp, so that users can share the article they are reading with there contacts, i got something that worked in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619418/how-do-i-implement-basic-share-social-buttons-with-font-awesome-fonts).

According to the answer:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=SHAREMESSAGE">Share on WhatsApp</a>
```

This worked but i want to share current URL when a user click the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Request#original_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<%= request.original_url %>">Share on WhatsApp</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use basic DOM concept with JS to get the current URL, like:

```
var x = document.URL
window.location.href = "whatsapp://send?text="+x
```